# Playing audio file in jsp

Tags: html, audio

1) Is there a way in java to stream an audio file from ftp on my jsp page?

2) How can I play an audio file in jsp without audio file being download on client browser (like live stream) - temporary internet files

please help with some code example

Comment: This is not a java or jsp question - more a HTML question.  I'm re-tagging it.

Answer (score 4):

Streaming audio from a file does not have anything to do with the JSP itself.

You want to embed your audio file into the page using HTML tags.  You can do this directly like:

```
<embed src="audiofile.mp3">
```

Or build something a bit more fancy using a Flash movie as an audio player, or find a JavaScript library.  [Here is a page on how to do it with various methods](http://designshack.co.uk/articles/html/four-quick-and-easy-ways-to-embed-mp3-files-into-your-site).

The JSP can provide the audio file name and perhaps other options, but that's all it has to do -- the rest is handled by plain old HTML tags.

You can find more information by searching the Web for the terms "embed" and "audio".

Answer (score 2):

If you're already on HTML5, just use [`<audio>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio) element, See also the [HTML Dog tutorial](http://htmldog.com/guides/html/advanced/embeddedcontent/).

```
<audio src="file.wav" controls="true" />
```

If you're not on HTML5 yet, audio in a webbpage is usually to be included by the HTML `<embed>` element (which uses the platform default player) or the HTML `<object>` element (wherein you can specify a more specific player for which the webbrowser can eventually automagically download the necessary plugin software).

```
<object data="file.wav" />
```

Either way, it should point to an URL which returns the audio stream. This can be just a static file in the public webcontent, next to the JSP file. E.g. http://example.com/context/file.wav. But when the audio file is stored outside the public webcontent or in a database, then you'd like to stream it via a Servlet. Basically just get an `InputStream` of it (using e.g. `FileInputStream`) and then write it to the `OutputStream` of the response along a correct set of response headers.

Noted should be that JSP is irrelevant in this particular question. It's just a view technology providing a template to write HTML in and send it to the webbrowser.

---

That said, websites which plays audio are generally considered annoying and generally scare off visitors. Keep this in mind if you consider User Experience important.

Comment: thnx for your replay 

I doing exactly what you're suggesting here, my concern is to some how avoid the audio file of being downloaded on client's machine (IE-Temporary Internet Files) , if you use embed tag it downloads the entire file first,
is there a way of avoiding this file download

Comment: Instead of the poor man's `<embed>`, use the `<object>` element and specify a player with settings supporting streaming audio. You can find [here](http://www.google.com/search?q=html+object+streaming+audio) several examples.